# Play System Sound With Swift In iOS 8 Beta 5

Tags: ios, ios8

I am trying to play short system sound with swift in my project , but can't make it work. I searched for the answer , unfortunately non of them were worked for me even if they worked for others . Here is my code .

```
//System Keyboard Tock Sound
func playInputClick() {

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tock", ofType: "caf")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
    var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(fileURL, &soundID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)

}
```

The objective-c version of this code was working fine , and now the swift version not working for me , when try to play the sound nothing is happening in the simulator , when I tap the button to play on the device it slows down the tapping action and makes no sound.
I can't figure out what causes the problem , is it the betas ? But exact the same code worked on the device for some people in this forum . maybe this is more about a question of calling C methods in swift.

This is from  System log:

`[MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.`

`Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 2743: (null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling X-Code solved my issue , I have no idea what was wrong. The above code only works on real-devices not on simulator, if somebody need to use the code .

Comment: Is **AudioServicesPlaySystemSound** still muted on simulator?